# How do I get every combination of letters using yield return and recursion?

Tags: c#, recursion, string-concatenation, yield-return

I have several lists of strings like so, from a possible list of several dozen:

```
1: { "A", "B", "C" }
2: { "1", "2", "3" }
3: { "D", "E", "F" }
```

These three were only picked as an example, and the user can pick from several dozen similar lists with varying number of elements. For another example, this is also a perfectly valid selection for a user:

```
25: { } // empty
 4: { "%", "!", "$", "@" }
16: { "I", "a", "b", "Y" }
 8: { ")", "z", "!", "8" }
```

What I want to do is get every combination of strings possible while keeping the 'order' of the lists. In other words, assuming we're looking at the first list, the first combination will be `A1D`, then `A1E`, then `A1F`, then `B1D`, then `B1E`, and so on and so forth. So far I've written this recursive algorithm:

```
public void Tester()
{
    var 2dList = new List { list1, list2, list3 };
    var answer = ReturnString(2dList).ToList();

    answer.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}

public IEnumerable<string> ReturnString(List<List<string>> list)
{
    if (!list.Any())
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    else
    {
        // for each letter in the top-most list...
        foreach (var letter in list.First())
        {
            // get the remaining lists minus the first one
            var nextList = list.Where(x => x != list.First()).ToList();

            // get the letter and recurse down to find the next
            yield return letter + ReturnString(nextList);
        }
    }
}
```

However, what I get in return is this instead:

```
AStringGeneration.StringGenerator+<ReturnString>d__11
BStringGeneration.StringGenerator+<ReturnString>d__11
CStringGeneration.StringGenerator+<ReturnString>d__11
```

`StringGeneration` is the name of the class that `ReturnString` is in. When I put a breakpoint on the `yield return letter + ...` line, it seems to iterate through `A`, `B`, and `C`, but doesn't actually recurse. I'm not sure what's going on here. Can anyone explain what is wrong with my algorithm?

Comment: list.Where(x => x != list.First()).ToList(); could probably be replaced with list.Skip(1)

Comment: @Grozz Thanks! I knew there had to have been an easier way of doing that :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enumerate the iterator:

```
foreach(string s in ReturnString(...)) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

This applies per iteration too:

```
foreach(string tail in ReturnString(nextList))
    yield return letter + tail;
```

Also, I suspect you can do something with SelectMany here.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to mention that the output that I get is exactly what gets displayed when using your code to enumerate the result from `ReturnString` (which should be plural). Also of interest is that, when putting a breakpoint on the `yield return letter + ...` line, it seems to iterate through `A`, `B`, and `C`, but doesn't actually recurse down to the next level.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have did it! Now I just need to figure out why :).

Comment: I'm interested in any possible `SelectMany` solutions for this question. I tried to understand how it works but it's currently beyond my understanding aside from the very basic cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
from x in l1
from y in l2
from z in l3
select x + y + + z
```

**Update:**

Here's an outline for an arbitrary version. I'll fill in details later.

```
private bool m_beforeStart;
private IList<IEnumerable<char>> m_lists;
private Stack<IEnumerator<char>> m_enumerators;

public bool MoveNext() {
    while (CurrentEnumerator != null && !CurrentEnumerator.MoveNext()) {
        RemoveLastChar(m_stringBuilder);
        PopEnumerator();
     }
     if (CurrentEnumerator == null && ! m_beforeStart) {
         return false;
     }
     m_beforeStart = false;
     while (PushEnumerator()) {
          if (!CurrenEnumerator.MoveNext()) {
              ClearEnumerators();
              return false;
          }
          m_stringBuilder.Append(
              m_currentEnumerator.Current
          );
      }
      return true;
}

public string Current {
    get {
        return m_stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}

private IEnumerator<char> CurrentEnumerator {
    get {
        return m_enumerators.Count != 0 ? m_enumerators.Peek() : null;
    }
}

private void PopEnumerator() {
    if (m_enumerators.Count != 0) {
        m_enumerators.Pop();
    }
}

private bool PushEnumerator() {
    if (m_enumerators.Count == m_lists.Count) {
        return false;
    }
    m_enumerators.Push(m_lists[m_enumerators.Count].GetEnumerator());
}
```

Comment: That assumes you know the depth, though

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the lists the user can choose from will be dynamic.

Comment: Yield isn't the best thing for that case. It doesn't handle recursion well. You can do it with a handcrafted IEnumerator implementation though.

Comment: You could use yield, but you would need a stack to maintain your own activation records.

Comment: btw, he has list of strings, not chars.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReturnString(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> matrix)
{
    if (matrix.Count() == 1)
        return matrix.First();

    return from letter in matrix.First()    // foreach letter in first list
           let tail = matrix.Skip(1)        // get tail lists
           let tailStrings = ReturnString(tail)   // recursively build lists of endings for each tail
           from ending in tailStrings       // foreach string in these tail endings
           select letter + ending;          // append letter from the first list to ending
}
```

call as `ReturnString(lst.Where(l => l.Any())` to skip empty sequences.

Comment: Your code works great and produces the same output as my updated code. However, I'm having a hard time understanding how it actually works and if asked to rewrite it, I would be unable to.

Comment: Instead of `return matrix.First()`, he could change the `matrix.Count() == 1` to `matrix.Count() == 0` instead and `return new List<string>()`.

Comment: fixed it to handle empty lists, it's a bit more tricky than that

Comment: btw, feeding matrix.SkipWhile(lst => !lst.Any()) to the first input would be more clear and efficient than doing it in the function

Comment: FYI: The string concatenations add an extra O(N^2) term to the runtime complexity. You may want to consider using a linked list instead, and then having a wrapper function that takes an IEnumerable<LinkedList<char>> and collapses that into an IEnumerable<string>.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that concatenating strings requires building a new string. So if you do:

string s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    s = s + "," + i.ToString();
}

You will build sum(i=1, n) strings, or n*(n+1) / 2. If you want to concatenate strings efficiently you should use a stringbuilder.

Comment: I really doubt that in this particular case `new StringBuilder(letter).Append(ending).ToString()` would yield better result than `letter + ending`, but it can be easily tested.

Comment: Btw, the problem kinda asks for efficient dynamic programming solution, but I'm not good at that.

Comment: I don't mean replace each string + with a string builder. I mean build a linked list (a shareable one like the InmutableList in the bcl extras library), and then do a final concat (using a string builder) in a wrapper over the final IEnumerable. The problem with your solution (as is) is that you do a string concat at each level of recursion.

Comment: @Grozz let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2004/discussion-between-scott-wisniewski-and-grozz)